# open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a countable union of non-overlapping closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Every open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a countable union of non-overlapping closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to know interesting and different proofs for this.

Here closed interval in $\mathbb{R}^n$ means the set $[a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2]\times...\times[a_n, b_n] $,where $[a_i , b_i]$ are real closed intervals for each $i$.

**Two intervals are non-overlapping if the intersection of their interior is empty**

Comment: As stated, this makes no sense for $n>1$. And for $n=1$, this is obviously not true.

Comment: What is a closed interval in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @5xum closed interval in $ \mathbb{R}^n $ is set of the form $[a_1, b_1] X [a_2, b_2] X.....[a_n,b_n] $ where $[a_i , b_i ] $ are real intervals.

Comment: @NarinderSingh Typically, we call that a closed box, not an interval.

Comment: @5xum in integration theory we call it closed interval.

Comment: @NarinderSingh A closed interval is a subset of $\mathbb R$ in every textbook I ever saw...

Answer (score 3):

Assume this is possible for $(0,1)\subset\Bbb R^1$. For the countable set $A$ of midpoints of the closed intervals, we have

- $A$ is not empty
- $A$ has no maximal and no minimal element
- if $a,b\in A$, $a<b$, then there exists $c\in A$, $a<c<b$.

It follows that $A$ is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$, i.e., there exists a bijection $f\colon A\to \Bbb Q $ such that $a<b\to f(a)<f(b)$. Let $x=\sup\{\,a\in A\mid f(a)<\sqrt 2\,\}$. Then $x$ is not covered by the given intervals.

Comment: Terry Tao's blog has a lovely alternative proof of this using the Baire Category Theorem: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/covering-a-non-closed-interval-by-disjoint-closed-intervals/

Comment: @TheoBendit there is a difference between non-overlapping and disjoint interval. two intervals are non-overlapping if the intersection of their interior is empty